# Run Gradle task on the first build of the day only

Tags: gradle, build, build.gradle

I have a task that fetches some data which updates daily but takes a few seconds. To save build times I'd like to only run that task once per day. I've read through the up to date section of the gradle docs but I'm still not clear on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

configure the inputs to have a date property

```
task onceADay {
   inputs.property("todaysDate", new Date().clearTime() )
   outputs.upToDateWhen { true }
}
```

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:task_input_output_runtime_api for more info on how its used. note this isn't a 24 hour thing though, it's once a calendar day thing.

Comment: That's perfectly fine. Could I trouble you for a little more in depth of an explanation of how this works?

Comment: This didn't seem to work, could you expand a bit on what's supposed to be going on?

Comment: @ZachSperske sorry i forgot about this but it's supposed to take in a property 'todaysDate' where we give it today's date (day month year) as the value. Everytime that task is ran, gradle will cache that value. if the next time that task is called has the same value given, that input is considered to be UP-TO-DATE. on the next date, it will get a different date than the cached one, making the task _not_ UP-TO-DATE. What is happening btw? its not running on the next day?

Comment: the task runs every time I build, doesn't ever seem to be considered up to date.

Comment: oh! there needs to be at least one output defined as well. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks so much, you just shaved a few seconds off our build times.

Comment: One last thing, could you explain why the output is needed?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the official answer, I just saw this note: [Also note that incremental build won’t work unless a task has at least one task output, although tasks usually have at least one input as well.](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:task_inputs_outputs).

Comment: So I have a `preBuild.doFirst`, how do I ensure that gets called only after that `todaysDate` property has been set?

Comment: You have to make sure that the property gets set in the "configuration phase", and then instead of passing in a regular object as second argument to `inputs.property()`, you would pass in a closure which resolves the value of the property. (`{ project.todaysDate }`)